# Make p:imageCropper area a fixed square

Tags: jsf, primefaces, crop, square

Is it possible to crop image proportionally using `<p:imageCropper>`?

```
<p:imageCropper value="#{registerPetForm.croppedImage}" image="#{registerPetForm.uploadedFilename}" />
```

I would restrict users to crop image only in square format:

```
  ______
 |      |  |  |
 |      |  |  |
 |______|  V  |
 -------->    |
 _____________|
```

So with same width and height. I want to avoid a rectangle format:

```
   __________
  |          |
  |__________|

   or
    _____
   |     |
   |     |      
   |     |
   |_____|
```

How can I achieve this with `<p:imageCropper>`?

Comment: You mean, you want to set the aspect ratio of the crop area to 1.0? Have you checked the  `<p:imageCropper>` [tag documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.2/core/primefaces-p/imageCropper.html) / [user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) / [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/cropper.xhtml) for clues?

Comment: i really never use aspectRatio and i dont know for what is used this attribute

Comment: thanks mate. aspectRatio is that what i looking for :)

Comment: If you don't know what something is for, there is always a search engine or translator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, the `aspectRatio` attribute can be used which takes a `double`. A value of `1.0` will make it an exact square.

```
<p:imageCropper ... aspectRatio="1.0" />
```

```
  ______
 |      |
 |      |
 |______|
```

The aspect ratio represents how many times the width should be of the height. So, a value less than `1.0`, e.g. `0.5`, will make the width to be `0.5` times of the height.

```
<p:imageCropper ... aspectRatio="0.5" />
```

```
  ______
 |      |
 |      |
 |      |
 |      |
 |______|
```

And, a value more than `1.0`, e.g. `1.5`, will make the width to be `1.5` times of the height.

```
<p:imageCropper ... aspectRatio="1.5" />
```

```
  ___________
 |           |
 |           |
 |___________|
```